# mysql time difference

Tags: mysql, date-arithmetic

I am trying to do a little spam filter with mysql. I want to check the last record a user has created in a table and compare it to the current time. The time created is stored as `date_created` with mysql `datetime` format.

I have tryed `TIMEDIFF()`, but I can't get it to work for me, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM database WHERE date_created> NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND user_id=17
```

If this query returns non-zero value, then there are rows, created on last hour by this user

Comment: are you about UNIX_TIMESTAMP ? It's strange to use it here if date_created is datetime

Comment: @halliewuud a little late to the party, but you can use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` to get the current datetime in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

To get the most recent record and time diff to current time for user `x`

```
SELECT
  tab.*,
  TIMEDIFF(NOW(), date_created) as diff
FROM tab
WHERE(userid = x)
ORDER BY date_created DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: replace `tab` with the name of the table, same as after `FROM`. Or use just `*,` that should work too.